# How to automate Instagram posting, handle post comments, and send private messages

Tags: python, express, automation, instagram-graph-api

I run a Telegram channel that shares deals from various sources, and I am seeking assistance in automating the process of posting these deals on Instagram and watching comments for specific replies and then replying then in comments and privately.

So the purpose is to automate Instagram posting, read and reply to comments, and send private messages using the Instagram Graph API or any other reliable API. I have already followed the necessary steps to access the Instagram Graph API, including creating a Facebook page, connecting it to an Instagram professional account, and creating a Facebook Developers app. I have also experimented with the Instagram Graph API Explorer tool.

However, I have encountered an issue where the access token provided in the Instagram Graph API explorer tool expires after approximately one hour. I would like to know how I can obtain a long-term access token that can be used in my Express, Python, or PHP script to perform these tasks.

Since I have limited knowledge of this API, I would appreciate a detailed explanation of the necessary steps involved in obtaining a long-term access token and utilizing it within my script. Any guidance or assistance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help, and I apologize for any mistakes or oversights in my understanding of the process.

Comment: This doc [Meta-Long-Lived Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived/) docs explain pretty clearly on how to generate long-lived tokens. Please let us know what exactly issue you are facing.